How to use variable in ${{ github.event.inputs }} , github workflow
I want to use a variable in ${{ github.event.inputs }} so that I can get the value of that particular input. This varibale value will keep changing in the loop.
name: workflow

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      build_version:
        description : 'Build Version'
        required: true
      abc:
        type: boolean
      xyz:
        type: boolean
  
jobs:
  getting_app_name:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: step1
        id: list_creation
        run: |
          declare -a names=()
          for option in abc xyz; do
            echo "option: $option"
            value=$(echo "${{ github.event.inputs }}" | jq -r ".$option")
            echo "value: $value"
            if [[ "$value" == "true" ]]; then
              deployment_names+=("$option")
            fi
          done
          echo "names: ${deployment_names[@]}"

But this is giving me error.
in this line: value=$(echo "${{ github.event.inputs }}" | jq -r ".$option")
Can you please help

What's the error?

I'd be pretty confident that ${{ github.event.inputs }} won't output a JSON string. You should try adding echo "${{ inputs }}" to see what format it does use

{{ github.event.inputs }} is an object, not a JSON-representation directly, so echo "${{ github.event.inputs }}" will evaluate to just Object, and that of course will not mean anything to jq.
So you need to convert it to JSON first with toJson:
value=$(echo '${{ toJson(github.event.inputs) }}' | jq -r ".$option")

Notice the change in quotation marks too, it needs to be '. Since the evaluation is done before the code is actually ran, with " it would evaluate to something like this:
    value=$(echo "{
    "abc": "true",
    "build_version": "1.2.3",
    "xyz": "true"
  }" | jq -r ".$option")

Which once again will fail when trying to parse nested quotations.
If you have special characters in your key, like hyphens, you can instead get the key with the syntax of '.["test-key"]'. To allow using a variable within that expression, you need to do the following:
value=$(echo '${{ toJson(github.event.inputs) }}' | jq -r --arg option "$option" '.[$option]')


Thanks. But I am facing issue when inplace of abc I have string which contain '-' like: "my-name". etc.
How can I do for this?

If you have special characters in the key, you can do this: jq -r --arg option "$option" '.[$option]'). I'll update my answer.
